# Scheduling - Combinations with repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I know there is a way to calculate combinations where repetition is allowed (something like ${{n+k}\choose{k}}$) but this is not quite what I'm asking about. In the problem I'm looking at (nurse scheduling/rostering problem) I want to show the number of possible schedules that can be generated with $n$ workers filling $k$ shifts. The problem arises in that workers can be repeated in the schedule BUT not infinitely. The number of times a worker is allowed to fill a shift is any number in a range from $a$ to $b$ (i.e. as long as a worker is above a minimum of $a$ shifts and below a maximum of $b$ shifts then the schedule may be counted as possible). I have never taken a probability/combinatorics class so I have very little knowledge in this topic beyond combinations and permutations. Let me know if the explanation of my problem makes sense and I will try to clarify it.

Comment: You can start by observing that you can suppose that the minimum shift $a$ is equal to 0. Indeed, as every worker should be above of $a$, it is enough to have the eventual $b-a$ shifts.

Comment: If this is a **practical** problem, you'd do well to give some figures. You say you have very little knowledge in this field, and giving actual figures might make the solution much simpler, and easier for you to understand.